# phpseclib with laravel unstable connection to switch

Tags: phpseclib

I am using phpseclib to conect with cisco switch.

```
    $ssh = new SSH2('169.254.170.30',22); 

    $ssh->login('lemi', 'a');
```

Sometimes it connects very fast few times in a row (when i reload a page), but sometimes  i get error message "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" also few times in a row. I am doing that in laravel. I do not want to prolong execution time. I can't figure out where is the problem. I think that it has some problems with sockets... I am getting error on this line (3031) of code in SSH2.php :

```
    $raw = stream_get_contents($this->fsock, $this->decrypt_block_size);
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: "*I am getting error on this line (3031) of code in SSH2.php*" What error are you getting? And what version of phpseclib are you using? https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52602 elaborates why `stream_get_contents` is used in case you're curious.

Comment: As far as the slow speeds...  try posting the SSH logs. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and `echo $ssh->getLog();` afterwards.

Comment: I found that "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" is not an error. It is not catchable. It is just like a message that php sends to you. I changed fsockopen  to pfsockopen and now i have more succesfull connections than unsuccesfull. Also i think that it has something to do with connection state.Whenever i have FIN_CLOSE and CLOSE_WAIT i cant connect.

Comment: What are you trying to do with phpseclib? I assume it's not timing out for you during your login attempt. Also, what version of phpseclib are you using?

Comment: I am trying to configure switch. To make something like putty, but web oriented and with php if possible. And for version, i dont know... I ran trough files and found no clues... When i delete $ssh->login('lemi', 'a'); i have no problems. Always getting new instance of SSH2. So login makes problem.

Comment: For the version...  how did you install phpseclib? Composer? Did you download a zip file? For the logging...  you could do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3);` to get real time logs and then post them.

Comment: It was already included in laravel. When i echo $ssh->getLog(); and when it fails i get this:
00000000  53:53:48:2d:31:2e:39:39:2d:43:69:73:63:6f:2d:31  SSH-1.99-Cisco-1
00000010  2e:32:35:0a                                      .25.

->
00000000  53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:70:68:70:73:65:63:6c:69  SSH-2.0-phpsecli
00000010  62:5f:32:2e:30:20:28:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:6c:2c:20  b_2.0 (openssl, 
00000020  62:63:6d:61:74:68:29:0d:0a                       bcmath).. 

but when it is ok, list is much longer.

Comment: idk. It seems almost like the server just isn't sending any more data. I think https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/pull/1162 So after the identification strings are exchanged the KEXINIT packets are exchanged. In older versions of phpseclib phpseclib would wait for the server to send the KEXINIT packet before it sent its own. With the latest version of phpseclib phpseclib sends the KEXINIT packet first. You say you're using phpseclib in Laravel. Maybe do `composer update` but, either way, I think upgrading your version of phpseclib is the answer.

Comment: It is. I upgrated it and it works now. Thanks!